# How to create a unique index containing multiple fields where one is a foreign key

Tags: sql, node.js, typeorm

I am trying to create an index with multiple fields, one of the field is a foriegn key to another table. However i get the following error:

> Error: Index "player_id_UNIQUE" contains column that is missing in the
>   entity (Earning): player_id

Given that player_id is a foriegn key that im joining how do i handle this

```
import { Column, Entity, Index, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";
import { PersonPlayer } from "./PersonPlayer";
import { Team } from "./Team";

    @Entity()
    @Index("player_id_UNIQUE", ["player_id", "period", "year"], { unique: true })
    export class Earning {

        @PrimaryColumn({length: 36})
        id: string;

        @Column({nullable: true})
        year: number;

        @Column({type: 'decimal', nullable: true})
        amount: number;

        @Column({nullable: true, length: 45})
        period: string;

        @ManyToOne(() => Team, {nullable: true})
        @JoinColumn({name: 'team_id'})
        team: Team;


        @ManyToOne(() => PersonPlayer, {nullable: true})
        @JoinColumn({name: 'player_id'})
        player: PersonPlayer;

        @Column({nullable: true, length: 45})
        dtype: string;

    }
```

When i generate this entity and create the sql table (without the index) i see `player_id` as one of the columns. But it appears that typeorm is not able to recognize right now with the index that player_id exists in the entity through the joincolumn relationship.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out @Kay? I'm running into the same issue now and cannot find the answer in the official documentation.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Yes, I changed`player: personPlayer` to be `player_id: PersonPlayer`. This works for us because our project is only to handle db migrations, although it would be nicer to have player as the name instead of player_id. But because we are not using the rest of the orm to make any business logic we didin't mind

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is completely undocumented so it took some playing around until I stumbled upon the correct syntax. You can actually use sub-properties in index definitions:

```
@Index("player_id_UNIQUE", ["player.id", "period", "year"], { unique: true })
```

That way, `player.id` is automatically mapped to `player_id` in the resulting SQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "player_id_UNIQUE" ON "user_earning" ("player_id", "period", "year")
```

Comment: you are saviour

Answer (score 1):

```
@Index(["player.id", "period", "year"])
```

Or Just do this !

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly declare `player_id` in `Earning` entity. The only change you need to make is to add

```js
@Column()
player_id: number
```

before `player` definition.

This way TypeORM recognizes `player_id` as a valid column which you can use in @Index or @Unique definition.

It is documented behaviour: https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/how-to-use-relation-id-without-joining-relation